# Problem of distinguishing connections to multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I'm a beginner in laravel 8, and I'm trying to make the site connect to several databases, in this case there are two at the moment.

To make the multiple connections I used this site: https://themewp.inform.click/fr/comment-utiliser-la-fonctionnalite-de-connexions-a-plusieurs-bases-de-donnees-de-laravel-sur-un-site-web/

I have my first connection called mysql, and the second is called mysql2. But the pages that have to use the first connection still go to the second one. I have specified the connection they should use. So I would like to know how to make them distinguish, or if there is a method to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you extinguish those 2 databases in your .env file? In your models you have the option to use the second or the first 'connection' and that way make the distinction

Comment: I did everything noted on the site I followed, I put which connection to use in model, but apparently it does not want